# Profile pictures work everywhere except People Search!

Tags: user-profile, search

I'm stumped. Profile pictures are appearing correctly everywhere in SharePoint except People Search results. Here's how I tested:

1. I did a full AD import.
2. I edited my profile, including the PictureURL property (display name: Picture) as well as a couple other properties.
3. I ran a full crawl of the MySites host.
4. I performed a People Search for my last name.
   -- Verified that all of the edited properties appear correctly, **except** the PictureURL.

I verified that the XSL wasn't the problem by using the following nifty XSL trick to display the raw search result XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xmp><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xmp>  
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Turns out the "pictureurl" tag in the search results has no value.

I checked the managed property settings for PictureURL, and it's using the out-of-the-box values:

```
ows_PictureURL(text)
People:PictureURL(text)
```

What could be going on? Do I have to reset the managed property somehow? I've never delved deeply into SharePoint search, so I'm hesitant to start poking around with the managed properties without direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: for some reason, I had unchecked the checkbox for "Indexed" on the Edit Profile Properties page  for PictureURL (on the SSP Admin site). I'm leaving this silly question here in case somebody else has as hard a time googling this as I had.

Comment: setting indexed would help ;-)

Comment: "Uncheck" the checkbox for "Indexed" worked for me. Thanks!